# GeoPandas | Legend not showing

Tags: python, geopandas, legend, plot

Goal: Show `legend`

I've set `legend=True` and no difference was made.

```
for i in list(range(NUM_SLIDES)):
    d = {'col1': ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Sue'], 'geometry': [foo[i], bar[i], sue[i]]}
    gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(d, crs='EPSG:4326').plot(legend=True, alpha=0.5, color=list(mcolors.BASE_COLORS.values()), aspect=1);
```

First Plot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(d, crs='EPSG:4326').plot(column='col1', legend=True, cmap='rainbow', alpha=0.5, aspect=1);
```

Swap `color` for `cmap='rainbow'`.

[image]

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74353314/16852041)